# Python pdf Download. Pdf can't be opened after downloading

Tags: python, pdf, urllib

I download a bunch of pdf files and archive them.
Most of the documents work fine but I have a problem with one.
The link to the document which doesn't work is:
https://www.ishares.com/de/professionelle-anleger/de/literature/fact-sheet/susm-ishares-msci-em-sri-ucits-etf-fund-fact-sheet-de-de.pdf 
When I download it normally, it just workds fine.
I tried two different approaches with python to download it.

```
response = requests.get('https://www.ishares.com/de/professionelle-anleger/de/literature/fact-sheet/susm-ishares-msci-em-sri-ucits-etf-fund-fact-sheet-de-de.pdf',
    stream=True)

    with open(
           'test.pdf',
            'wb') as r:
        for chunk in response.iter_content(2000):
            r.write(chunk)
        r.close()
```

Second approach:

```
def pdfDownload(url):
    response = requests.get(url)
    expdf = response.content
    egpdf = open('test.pdf', 'wb')
    egpdf.write(expdf)
    egpdf.close()
```

In both cases I get an error message when I try to open it afterwards.

Comment: Did you think of comparing your "good" and "bad" downloads? What are the differences?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to replace your url with this

```
https://www.ishares.com/de/professionelle-anleger/de/literature/fact-sheet/susm-ishares-msci-em-sri-ucits-etf-fund-fact-sheet-de-de.pdf?switchLocale=y&siteEntryPassthrough=true
```

Comment: Works perfect. Thanks! Could you briefly explain what this additional code does?

Comment: the link you have is not a direct pdf download link if you go to browser with your link it will open a web page then you have to click a button on that page to download the pdf

Comment: @j.DOE did you got it?

Comment: Thanks. I get what you mean but I don't have to klick on any button, when I enter my url in my browser. Maybe that's because of my browser settings.

Comment: @j.DOE  that might be the case . so if the answer helped you it would be great if you just mark it as correct or upvote the answer thanks